# Why do computers running Windows benefit more from regular restarts than other OSes?

Tags: linux, windows

When you shut down a windows computer, it gets faster (if it's been on for a while). I notice that most, if not all, linux distros gain nearly nothing from restarts. In fact, I was actually suggested to restart my server (running Debian, a Linux OS) as little as possible in [this serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/555755/is-restarting-a-vps-used-as-a-web-server-regularly-good). I have a friend who uses Mint as their desktop OS and another who uses Ubuntu as theirs and they claim they almost never restart it, and have not noticed any downsides. Also, when installing anything in Linux (be it via command line using `apt-get` or installing it with a Desktop GUI) you don't have to restart the computer for it to install fully, unlike Windows. Why?

Comment: I never reboot my Windows to make it faster. This is nonsense. I reboot it once per month after patchday. Otherwise I only use hibernation to store the current state of running tools to continue the next day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- When you turn off the computer does not need to worry about the burden of Windows, thus aleviating the slowness !!

I believe you will find rebooting a Windows system will give varying results depending on whats installed.   You will probably find the issue is (a) Code running in the background which is not stopped when programs exit - ie bad drivers and (b) Memory leaks.

While it is true that you virtually never need to reboot a Linux computer to fix speed issues, Firefox still leaks like a sieve - particularly with plugins, starts swapping and requires to be killed to get things working again "on a default ubuntu or centos install".  Interestingly enough, tweeking memory management to reduce swapping (using swappiness) makes a huge difference - the moral of this paragraph being "Memory Management is important, and if not handled correctly requires the offending code to be killed"